install ms sql server on ubuntu desktop 24
Installing ms sql server but this error was generated after installing ms sql server
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. How can i resolve this?
